# What character did Nolan North play in "The Rickchurian Mortydate"?

Tags: character-identification, rick-and-morty

In the credits of season 3 episode 10 "The Rickchurian Mortydate" of *Rick and Morty* Nolan North is credited as starring. However, I didn't recognize his voice in the episode and can't find information on who he played online. **Who did he voice in this episode?**